# Using sub() to extract after a character over multiple columns

Tags: r, extract

consider the following code

```
x <- c('2','75% (3/4)','80% (4/5)','70% (7/10)','90% (9/10)') 
y <- c('1', '50% (1/2)', '25% (1/4)', '30% (3/10)', '40% (2/5)')

df <- data.frame(rbind(x, y))
```

I would like to extract the values before the % sign i.e. the whole numbers.

I understand that I can do this using the following:

```
df$X2 <- sub("%.*", "", df$X2)
```

But to avoid copy and pasting, and going through each column, is there a way to do it in one step?

I have tried to do the following:

```
df[-1] <- sub("%.*", "", df[-1])
```

But this leaves the format as 'c("75' which is not what I am after - what has gone wrong here?
Is there another suitable way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R:

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, sub, pattern = "%.*", replacement = "")
df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# x  2 75 80 70 90
# y  1 50 25 30 40
```

The `df[] <-` is necessary because by default, `lapply` returns a `list` (not a `data.frame`). By using `df[]` on the LHS of the assignment, the *contents* of the columns are replaced within the structure of the frame. This also works well when operating on a subset of columns, as in

```r
df[c(2,3,5)] <- lapply(df[c(2,3,5)], sub, pattern = "%.*", replacement = "")
```

which is admittedly not what you want here, but provides a way to customize which columns are affected.

The `lapply(df, sub, ...)` is identical to the use of an anonymous function:

```r
lapply(df, function(z) sub("%.*", "", z))
```

Because the elements of the argument (`df` here) are passed as the first argument to the function (which would be `pattern=`), we explicitly pass the constant values to those as supplement arguments to `lapply`, where anything after the first two arguments (`X`, our `df`; and `FUN`) are provided as unchanging arguments to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would likely be to do this using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, across(everything(), stringr::str_remove, "%.*"))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
x  2 75 80 70 90
y  1 50 25 30 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might be the output you were looking for?

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
  df[,i] <- sub("%.*", "", df[,i])
}
print(df)
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
x  2 75 80 70 90
y  1 50 25 30 40
```

Comment: I actually did try to do something like this! But instead of df[ ,i], I was doing df[i]

Comment: Word of warning for `df[,i]`: with base `data.frame`s and when `length(i) == 1`, then this returns a vector; if `length(i) > 1`, or always for `tbl_df` and `data.table`, this returns a `tbl_df` or `data.table` (with `length(i)` columns), not a vector. `sub(..., df[,i])` when `df[,i]` is not a vector is certainly not useful.